# How Can I display all activated and none activated (dead)neurons using Pycaffe?

Tags: caffe, pycaffe

I want to get the percentage of dead neurons as described [here](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/5706/what-is-the-dying-relu-problem-in-neural-networks) in a specific layer and then plot them so that I can know if the majority of neurons are learning or not.
I tried the following snippet :

```
feat = net.blobs['fc'].data[0]
```

This works with FC layers, but for Conv layers, I am faced with a feature map for each neuron, and if I flatten that, that wouldn't help either since I want to plot each neurons status (being dead or not).
What should I do here? sum up all features in each feature-map like this ?

```
n=np.sum(feat,axis=1).sum(1)
```

Is this the correct way ?

By the way this is the latest code that I wrote for this :

```
def Show_all_dead_neurons(net):
    neurons=[]
    for layer_name, blob in net.blobs.items():
        feat = net.blobs[layer_name].data[0]
        if((len(feat.shape) <3) or ("pool" in layer_name)):
            continue;
        print(layer_name + '\t' + str(blob.data[0].shape))    
        n = np.sum(feat,axis=1).sum(1)
        x = n[n == 0]
        print(len(x))
        neurons.append(x)
    s = 0
    for i in range(len(neurons)):
        s += np.sum(len(neurons[i]))
    print('all dead neurons:',s)
```

Comment: Whats with the downvote?!

Comment: what do you mean by "dead neurons"? what exactly are you trying to visualize?

Comment: @Shai, I meant dead relu units, I want to get the number of neurons for each layer that are literally doing nothing. : https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/5706/what-is-the-dying-relu-problem-in-neural-networks

Comment: I'm trying to replicate the figure in page 4 of this paper : http://mipal.snu.ac.kr/images/1/16/Dropout_ACCV2016.pdf